# Can I change the width of a view inside a viewpager?

Tags: android, layout, android-viewpager

I'm currently using a Viewpager with 3 fragment. I would like to know if I can change the width of the first fragment.

In fact , I try this do to something like the category menu in the android play store when you watching it with tablet, it looks like a fragment but its not taking all the space when swiping to it so you still see the fragment next to it (i don't know if i'm clear). I was wondering if I could simply do that by changing the width of the first fragment from MATCH_PARENT to a fixed value, i don't even know if the result of this could be nice.

i tried setLayoutParams() , set it in the xml , nothing seems to work. the fragment still match parent.

Comment: How about taking the ViewPager source code and changing the onDraw() or similar method to your liking?

Comment: yes i know i can , but in first i was looking for something out-of-the-box,its stupid to modify source if something simmilar already exist (and surely better coded than me), now i know it doesn't exist so i think i may look into source, thanks for the hint anyway :p

Comment: Of course:) I was just "thinking on screen"

Comment: I think PagerAdapter.getPageWidth might do what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ViewPager, it is not supported. You have to write your own ViewGroup class, or you might try something as i answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569208/swipe-half-page-in-a-viewpager-from-compatibility-pack/10575613#10575613).

Comment: ViewGroup with LayoutParams MatchParent for width and height helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you might want to try setting a negative margin on the pages in the `ViewPager`, using [`setPageMargin(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setPageMargin%28int%29). See also this answer I provided not too long ago on a similar question:

- [Can I set viewpager's item width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168087/can-i-set-viewpagers-item-width/10168134#10168134)

Comment: i'll try that, thanks for the hint. i'll post here if the result are good enough