# ViewPager partial view of next page first time only

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to tell the user that s/he can swipe to change page. So I want to show a partial view of the next page. But that only the very first time. So I figure I would use the code

```
boolean mFirstTime = true;
@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
  if (position == 0 && mFirstTime) {
    mFirstTime = false;
    return 0.9f;
  }
  return 1f;
}
```

But my `mFirstTime` has no apparent effect. Does anyone know a way to achieve my end? I image I could use a listener of sort, but I don't know what would go inside the listener.

**Update**

Alternatively I tried the snippet below to no avail.

```
myPager.beginFakeDrag();
myPager.fakeDragBy(Utils.dpToPx(this, 50));
myPager.endFakeDrag();
```

where the subroutine is

```
public static int dpToPx(Context context, int dp) {
  return (int) Math.ceil(dp * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10772383/2136812

Comment: does your page actually shrink ? or it doesnt grow back to full size after it shrank ?

Comment: @LenaBru for the first alternative it actually shrinks. But it does not return to full size if user swipes forward and then backward to the first page. So I thought the second alternative would work for me. But it does not work either. Really I want the view to jigger a little so the user sees he/she can swipe. That is the exact design I want.

Comment: which ViewPager adapter are you using?

Comment: @LenaBru basically for the first alternative I can see that the system is caching the value returned by `getPageWidth`. My suspicion is if I could keep that from happening that would solve the problem.

Comment: i just explained in my edited answer how to "refresh the system cache"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following for it to work.

1. if you're not extending FragmentStatePagerAdapter -> you need to extand that instead of just PagerAdapter
2. You need to override the method

   ```
   @Override
   public int getItemPosition(Object obj){

   return POSITION_NONE; //will cause data reload
   }
   ```

and when you're ready to display the page at full size, call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

which will cause the `getPageWidth()` to be called for each page again, making it grow

Comment: Many thanks. I was missing `getItemPosition`. Also it's `getItemPosition(Object obj)`.

Comment: I found this answer when i was thinking that viewpager worked exactly like a listview. Which apparently it does not. And this fixed it for me.